# how to do dict comprehension for multiple for and if loops in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

i have a code like below:

```
out={}
for each_val in values["data"]['values']:
    if each_val['value'].strip() != '':
       if 'frequency' in each_val:
           out[each_val['value']] = each_val['frequency']
       else:
           out[each_val['value']] = None
```

i am trying to make it one line with dict comprehension but not able to do it with 2 if loops inside for loop. Below is the code I tried but getting warnings and errors

```
out = {each_val['value']: each_val['frequency'] if 'frequency' in each_val and if each_val['value'].strip() != '' else None for each_val in values["data"]['values']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the filter as an `if` clause in the comprehension. Also, use the `dict.get` method to default the value to `None` when a key is not found in the dict:

```
out = {
    each_val['value']: each_val.get('frequency')
    for each_val in values["data"]['values']
    if each_val['value'].strip() != ''
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `if` after `and`

```
out = {each_val['value']: each_val['frequency'] if 'frequency' in each_val and each_val['value'].strip() != '' else None for each_val in values["data"]['values']}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).